# Symfony Snappy Bundle doesn't load css

Tags: css, symfony, wkhtmltopdf, snappy

I have an issue with pdf creation on Snappy pdf Bundle: it seems not to load the css file I try to import.

I even tried by using an absolute url but it doesn't work either.

this is my code:

```
{% block body %}
       {# Layout for PDF files #}
     <p>Cliente: {{ cliente.nome }}</p>
{% endblock %}





 <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">                 </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('main.css') }}">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('base.min.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('fancy.min.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('./main1.css') }}"/>
```

Comment: You might want to link these css into the `head` block instead..

Comment: don't change nothing